# Mostrar posición actual sobre imagen de un Google Map almacenada en memoria local

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-v3

Utilizo un método para descargar imágenes del mapa (Google Map snapshot) y guardarlas en memoria, para después mostrarlas en una lista como imágenes en miniatura con el nombre del archivo. Cuando pulsas sobre cada miniatura, te muestra la imagen en grande (ImageView).

¿Cómo podría mostrar la posición actual en la imagen cuando esta abierta, en el caso de que la posición se encontrase dentro de las coordenadas de la imagen?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Posición actual yo entiendo por la ruta donde esta almacenada. si no es así explícanos mejor tu problema.

Con la función de `Environment` esta:

Nos da solo la externa pero para los dispositivos con mas de una memoria esto se complica.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Esta función no nos da la ruta interna:

```
Environment.getDataDirectory();
```

Esta función no nos da la ruta interna. Nos da la ruta data de la aplicación,algo así como:

```
/data
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero no era exactamente a lo que me refería. Querría saber la posición actual del usuario, es decir, la ubicación en la que se encuentra, algo así como marcar un punto en las coordenadas donde esté dentro de la imagen. (Por ejemplo, una imagen del mapa de Londres, una vez esté allí y abra la imagen, indique la ubicación en esa zona) Perdón por no haberme expresado bien, muchas gracias @AshleyG.